# Setting makeSortable() on a grid column does not work as intended

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I have just started using Agile Toolkit 4.2.0 for a simple CRUD web application, and so far I'm very impressed with the framework, except that I can't get column sorting to function properly.

Updating the dvdrental page/video.php example with an added line at the end for setting `makeSortable()` does not seem to work as intended. In all the browsers I have tested the code on so far (Firefox 12, Chrome 18, Opera 11.62 and IE 9), it only outputs a malformed line of HTML before the 'Year' column header.

```
class page_video extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->api->auth->check();

        $grid = $this->add('MVCGrid');
        $grid->setModel('Movie');

        $grid->getColumn('year')->makeSortable(); 
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and hopefully it's not a simple error caused by my own ineptitude with this new tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an issue opened for this, https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/46

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub link, nice to know that this issue is being looked into, hopefully it will be resolved soon.

Comment: That has now been properly resolved and in "master" branch of Git. It will also be in 4.2.1 of Agile Toolkit (along with the fix for autocomplete)